# Use http.client to login to the online Farasa lemmatizer and lemmatize content

Tags: python, json, http

I am trying to use the code for Farasa lemmatizer into my code to lemmatize json files that contain Arabic language. here is the link to the code http://alt.qcri.org/farasa/

I read all the json files and this returned a list of lists of strings. My question how can I feed this list of lists to the code on the website of farasa to start the process of lemmatization. I am trying to understand what is (payload) but I couldnot

Here is what I attempted

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(“farasa-api.qcri.org”) 
payload = “{\”text\”: \”هذا مثال بسيط\”}”

headers = { ‘content-type’: “application/json”, ‘cache-control’: “no-cache”, }

conn.request(“POST”, “/msa/webapi/lemma”, payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read()

print(data.decode(“utf-8”))
```

Comment: payload dictionary with single string which you send to server. If you need to send more strings then use `for` loop and send every string separatelly.

Answer (score 1):

the payload is a string, and inside this string is a dictionary, so to use a variable instead of the string directly, you should use this code:

```
import json
import http.client

text = '"هذا مثال بسيط"'
text = text.replace('"', '')
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("farasa-api.qcri.org")
payload = "{\"text\":\"%s\"}"% text
payload = payload.encode('utf-8')

headers = { 'content-type': "application/json", 'cache-control': "no-cache", }

conn.request("POST", "/msa/webapi/lemma", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()

data = res.read().decode('utf-8')
data_dict = json.loads(data)
```

you can access the list of tokens using:

```
data_dict['result']
```

the output will be:

```
['هذا', 'مثال', 'بسيط']
```